# How to match Questions with Answers in django

Tags: python, django

Please explain me how to match the Answer of a particular Question in django.
Right Now I am facing the issue that whatever the user inputs in the form if it exits in Answer database it returns True, **But what I want is that whatever the user inputs should be matched with the Answer of that particular Question and not any of the Answers present.**

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from PIL import Image
User=get_user_model()
# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question_name=models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True,default=' ')
    question_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='levels/')
    question_text=models.TextField(blank=True,max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.question_name)
    class Meta:
        ordering= ["question_name"]

class Answer(models.Model):
    question_relation=models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Answer,Question
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from . import views
class CheckAnswer(forms.Form):
    your_answer=forms.CharField(label='Answer')
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data=super(CheckAnswer,self).clean()
        response=cleaned_data.get("your_answer")
        try:
            p = Answer.objects.get(answer__iexact=response)
        except Answer.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong Answer.")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import *
from . import models
from django import forms
from .forms import CheckAnswer
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Question
from dashboard.models import UserLoggedIn

# Create your views here.
@login_required
def Arena1(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CheckAnswer(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('thanks')
    else:
        form=CheckAnswer()
    args={'form':form}
    return render(request,'levels/arena1.html',args)
```

I think the concept of pk will be used but I dont know how to implement it 
Please update my code that solves this problem.

Comment: But here you have not stored a `Question`(id) in your `Form`, so there is no "related" question here.

Comment: So could you please tell changes needed to do in the code-@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Please tell where in forms.py to pass this attr. and how?
It would be highly kindful of you-@WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1):

First of All, Matching the Question would Require you to Store of Provide the Question to the Function Somehow. What You can do it use a Global Variable or a Container in which you would set the value while rendering the Question and then Import it to forms.py and set the `your_question = Question`

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Answer,Question
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from . import views
class CheckAnswer(forms.Form):
    your_answer=forms.CharField(label='Answer')
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data=super(CheckAnswer,self).clean()
        response=cleaned_data.get("your_answer")
        try:
            p = Answer.objects.get(answer__iexact=response)
            if(your_answer == p.answer and your_question == p.question_relation.question_text): #user inputs should be matched with the Answer of that particular Question
                #Code To Run for Correct Answer Goes Here
            else:
                #The Answer is Wrong or Does not Match the Particular Question
                raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong Answer.")
        except Answer.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong Answer.")
```

Comment: Thanks!
But in my case the question is actually the image which would be loaded in html and user would analyse the image and then give input (basically see the image and guess the image). So how can image be declared Globally. The images are uploaded in the database and thrn rendered into Html -@Syed Faizan

Comment: Is there any method to use use field say 'score' from a model in other app of same project so that if answer to question is correct the value in 'score' can be incremented.??

Comment: The image is stored in database and Answers table had the correct answer. So make a Foreign Key to the Question Image. See When you render the image in template it comes from the database right? If so, share that model and its fields.

Comment: Yes, you can totally access models from another App as: from AppName.models import modelName